# How to update Multiple rows Order By Clause in Select Statement?

Tags: oracle, select, sql-update, sql-order-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am aware that we cant use Order By Clause in Update Statement. but my question is i am trying to run the below query and i am not sure why i am getting the error message. please help me solve this and what is the exact purpose of Exists in Oracle.
Thanks in Advance guys.

> update cars2 set vehicle_number = Seq_vehiclenumber.nextval where Exists (select * from CARS2 order by model);
>
> **Error Message :** SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>
> Desc cars2;
>
> Name             Null     Type
>
> ---
>
> VEHICLEID         NOT NULL NUMBER
>
> BRAND             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
>
> MODEL             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
>
> VEHICLE_TYPE               VARCHAR2(30)
>
> FUEL_TYPE                  VARCHAR2(30)
>
> TRANSMISSION_TYPE          VARCHAR2(30)
>
> GEARBOX                    NUMBER
>
> DRIVE_TYPE                 VARCHAR2(30)
>
> VEHICLE_NUMBER             NUMBER

Comment: I think that `Exists (select * from CARS2 order by model)` is always true, at least table car2 is empty. Can you explain a bit what you really want to do?

Comment: I created a table named "CARS2". 
Then i created a Sequence named "Seq_vehiclenumber" 
Then i inserted few rows in it.

Now all the rows under Vehicle_Number column are null, so i wanted to update those rows by using "Order BY" Clause in Model Column.

when i Execute the below, its executing successfully, 

> update cars2 set vehicle_number = Seq_vehiclenumber.nextval

But when i execute using Order by its throwing error message,

>update cars2 set vehicle_number = Seq_vehiclenumber.nextval where Exists (select * from CARS2 order by model);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sequence to enumerate already existing rows. You can enumerate cars using this `update`:

```
update cars2 set vehicleid = 
  (select rn 
    from (
      select row_number() over (order by model, brand) rn, model, brand 
        from cars2 order by model, brand ) temp
    where temp.model = cars2.model and temp.brand = cars2.brand)
```

Virtual column `rn` is created with analytic function [row_number()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) working on order `model, brand`. 
This `rn` is the number used then to enumerate cars in proper order.

This update will not work if you have duplicated pairs (model, brand).

I don't know what is the purpose of sequence `Seq_vehiclenumber`, if you want use it later to automatically fill vehicleid you have to create trigger to tie sequence to table.
But this sequence will not magically renumber all existing rows, to get them in proper order simply `select ... order by ...`

As for this part of your question *"what is the exact purpose of Exists in Oracle"* - `exists` is used for example 
when we want to select persons who have car, something like here:

```
select persons.id, persons.name 
  from persons 
  where exists (select * from cars where cars.owner_id = persons.id)
```

More examples [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exists.php).